# Does teleportation count as movement for a Tabaxi's Feline Agility trait?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, racial-traits, teleportation, tabaxi

A Tabaxi, after using his Feline Agility trait to double his movement speed for a turn, must then move 0 feet on a subsequent turn in order for his trait to recharge.

If the Tabaxi teleports, does it count as movement for his trait? (If so, this means that the trait won't recharge on that turn.)

Comment: Note that this question has follow-on implications regarding any area effects that activate upon "moving into the area" (as opposed to "entering the area", which would probably still work).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Movement is a defined term in the game.  On pages 181-182 of the PHB it goes into how movement works.  Teleportation doesn't use movement or speed, so you could teleport via *misty step*, *dimension door* or the like without spending movement on that turn.  Spells are generally an action or bonus action to cast but don't cost movement.  Similarly, if you misty step 30 feet away, you can still use your movement to get even farther.

Answer (score 14):

No, it does not.

All forms of teleportation in the game use actions (or bonus actions, or maybe reactions) to use; none of them use movement, and thus none of them would prevent recharging the Feline Agility.

Comment: apart from tree stride... "You must use 5 feet of movement to enter a tree."

Answer (score 2):

#### No, teleportation doesn't involve movement unless it says it does

The [*dimension door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) spell description states, in part:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot
> within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired. It can be a
> place you can see, one you can visualize, or one you can describe by
> stating distance and direction, such as "200 feet straight downward"
> or "upward to the northwest at a 45- degree angle, 300 feet."

Nowhere in the description of this spell does it say that "the caster casts the spell, then must step through a door that appears", which would use up movement.

Therefore, it depends on what type of teleport they're using.

If they were to use the [*arcane gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-gate) spell (PHB, p. 214), for example, then it would require stepping into the circle:

> You create linked teleportation portals that remain open for the
> duration. Choose two points on the ground that you can see, one point
> within 10 feet of you and one point within 500 feet of you. A circular
> portal, 10 feet in diameter, opens over each point. If the portal
> would open in the space occupied by a creature, the spell fails, and
> the casting is lost.
>
> The portals are two-dimensional glowing rings filled with mist,
> hovering inches from the ground and perpendicular to it at the points
> you choose. A ring is visible only from one side (your choice), which
> is the side that functions as a portal.
>
> Any creature or object entering the portal exits from the other portal
> as if the two were adjacent to each other; passing through a portal
> from the nonportal side has no effect. The mist that fills each portal
> is opaque and blocks vision through it. On your turn, you can rotate
> the rings as a bonus action so that the active side faces in a
> different direction.